# GWT Sorting after filtering a table

Tags: gwt

I have a simple table (CellTable) and a TextBox for filter.

Values for CellTable I take from backend. After list of items is loaded I can put some filter string to get suitable result. To filter list from dataprovider I use a predicate. After filtering I set result to CellTable.

Like here:

```
    void onFilterNameKeyUp(KeyUpEvent e) {
        List<CustomerDTO> filtered = this.dataProvider.getList();
        Predicate<CustomerDTO> filter = new Predicate<CustomerDTO>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(CustomerDTO input) {
                if (input.getName() == null) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return input.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .contains(filterName.getValue().toLowerCase());
                }
            }
        };

    filtered = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(this.dataProvider.getList(), filter));
    this.customerList.setRowCount(filtered.size(), true);
    this.customerList.setRowData(0, filtered);  
}

    this.dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<CustomerDTO>();
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(this.customerList);
    final ListHandler<CustomerDTO> sortHandler = new ListHandler<CustomerDTO>(
            this.dataProvider.getList());
    this.customerList.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);
    this.customerList.getColumnSortList().push(this.rbKeyNameColumn);
```

Everything work fine but I have also a sort handler for first column of this table and when I want to sort a list then I'm sorting original list of items.

How to solve this problem? It means that I want to sort and display filtered list instead of original list from dataprovider.

Comment: Can you paste the code snipped that binds the CellTable to the dataProvider variable. The cellTable sort event will call sorting on the the underlying data provider (don't see in this code if that is this.customerList or this.dataProvider)

Comment: this.dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<CustomerDTO>();
  dataProvider.addDataDisplay(this.customerList);
  final ListHandler<CustomerDTO> sortHandler = new ListHandler<CustomerDTO>(
    this.dataProvider.getList());
  this.customerList.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);
  this.customerList.getColumnSortList().push(this.rbKeyNameColumn);

Answer (score 0):

I have a table changing content after receiving some data from the server. This is my approach:

> `public void onSuccess(List<List<String>> result) {
>                   List<Product> list = dataProvider.getList();
>                   list.clear();
>                   r_tableproducts.setRowCount(result.size());
>                   for (List<String> l : result) {
>                       list.add(new Product(l));
>                   }
>                   r_tableproducts.getColumnSortList().clear();
>                   r_tableproducts.getColumnSortList().push(r_tableproducts.getColumn(1));
>               ColumnSortEvent.fire(r_tableproducts,r_tableproducts.getColumnSortList());
>               }`

This sorts my list using 2nd column after reciving new data (overriding all old data).

Maybe try this approach? Filter your data in a new list and modify the list your dataProvider provides you, adding all elements.

Something like:

> `List<CustomerDTO> result = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(this.dataProvider.getList(), filter));
>   this.customerList.setRowCount(result.size(), true);
>   this.dataProvider.getList().clear();
>   this.dataProvider.getList().addAll(result);`

Comment: The same effect. Sorting is working for list of items from dataProvider not for filtered items.

Comment: Corrected my answer, try the code above and report if that works.

Comment: But look all the time you need to the call backend to get unfiltered list of items. In my case there are more the five thousend of itmes. You call clear() method on dataprovider it means that when you remove part of filter string you will never get back a original list and you need to call backend again.

Comment: If you need to keep your original list and then update the rows being shown, filter the original list and then call `this.dataProvider.setList(filtered);` with the list you've filtered.

Don't mix setRowData and dataProvider in the same code. If you're using dataProvider, the changes to the table should be done on the list `dataProvider.getList();` returns to you.

[Info](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#data-provider) on GWT Data Providers.

Comment: If you call this.dataProvider.setList(filtered) then you lost original list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the dataProvider that holds the full list and provide a separate "filtered" data provider that will be driving the display of the cellTable. The cellTable in below example is bound to a filteredDataProvider for sorting, display purposes. 
The code below is to give a general idea and therefore may not be syntactically accurate.

```
void onFilterNameKeyUp(KeyUpEvent e) {
    List<CustomerDTO> filtered = this.dataProvider.getList();
    Predicate<CustomerDTO> filter = new Predicate<CustomerDTO>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(CustomerDTO input) {
            if (input.getName() == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return input.getName().toLowerCase()
                        .contains(filterName.getValue().toLowerCase());
            }
        }
    };

    filtered = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(this.dataProvider.getList(), filter));
    this.customerList.setRowCount(filtered.size(), true);
    this.filteredDataProvider.getList().clear();
    this.filteredDataProvider.getList().addAll(filtered); 
}

    this.dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<CustomerDTO>();
    // Code here to populate the dataProvider
    this.filteredDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<CustomerDTO>();
    // Creating separate DataProvider to hold the filtered set
    this.filteredDataProvider.getList().addAll(this.dataProvider.getList());
    filteredDataProvider.addDataDisplay(this.customerList);
    //        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(this.customerList);
    // Sort Handler uses filteredDataProvider instead of the dataProvider with full list
    final ListHandler<CustomerDTO> sortHandler = new ListHandler<CustomerDTO>(
            this.filteredDataProvider.getList());
    this.customerList.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);
    this.customerList.getColumnSortList().push(this.rbKeyNameColumn);
```